# Index Of in Cocoa

Tags: ios, swift, macos, cocoa

I'm used to making iPhone apps but now I need to make a Mac app. 
I thus have to switch to the Cocoa framework.

Is there anything similar to the array.index(of: ) in Cocoa?

iOS example:

```
let string = "Hello.World"
let needle: Character = "."
if let idx = string.characters.index(of: needle) {
    let pos = string.characters.distance(from: string.startIndex, to: idx)
    print("Found \(needle) at position \(pos)")
}
else {
    print("Not found")
}
```

The actual code I'm having problems with is here:

```
func checkBoxTapped(_ sender: NSButton) {
    if (sender.state == 1) {
        self.selectedReferrals.append(self.referralApplicationList[sender.tag])
    }
    if (sender.state == 0) {
        // Remove
        // self.referralApplicationList[sender.tag]
        // let foofoo = self.referralApplicationList.indexOf(self.referralApplicationList[sender.tag])
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? What are you trying to find the index of?

Comment: I've got a list of items with checkboxes. I'll let the user check which ones need to be added for a certain action. I want the user to also be able to remove items from the array.

Comment: Can you include the code that you're having problems with?

Comment: Added my actual function. Hope my question makes sense

Comment: The behavior of `String` in iOS and macOS is identical. But there is a difference between Swift 3 and 4

Comment: Use Set<Int>. inert button tag in the set when its selected and vice versa.

Comment: @RutgerHuijsmans: Check indexOf syntax; you are using indexOf instead of index(of:)

Answer (score 0):

Your question has nothing to do with Cocoa or macOS versus iOS at all. Really what you are asking is how to get an `index(of:)` function on a Swift array, and the answer to that is the elements in the array need to be `Equatable`.

In your iOS example, `characters` is an instance of `String.CharacterView` which explicitly has an `index(of:)` function.

In your Mac example, in which you don't provide enough info, the `selectedReferrals` variable is presumably an `Array` of some `Referral` type; eg a `[Referral]`. For there to be a similar `index(of:)` your `Referral` type needs to implement the `Equatable` protocol. Otherwise you'd need to use something like `index(where:)` to find the one you want.